# Entity Framework 5 stored procedure with multiple result sets

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm currently coding with asp.net mvc 4.5 and EF5 Beta 2 and I have a stored procedure which returns multiple result sets. I've found [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure.aspx) and it says that the newer version (which I'm using) already has support for multiple result sets.

Now I can't seem to find that support. As I'm fairly new to the EF altogether, I hope I'm not doing something wrong.

I have no corresponding entities in my database for the result sets created.

Comment: Are you using code first or database first (EDMX)?

Comment: Oops, seems I forgot to include that; I'm using Database first (.edmx)

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696190%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) it is still mentioned as new feature...

Answer (score 4):

The core EF libraries support multi result set procedures.  Unfortunately the designer does not -- and it's not clear if it will upon release.

I too found the documentation a bit sparse, particularly for returning multiple entity  types (as opposed to complex types).  Fortunately, manually editing the EDMX isn't too complicated.   I wrote up a blog post on topic ....

[Entity Framework 5 – Multiple Entity-Typed Result Sets from a Stored Procedure](http://milesquaretech.com/Blog/post/2012/03/19/Entity-Framework-5-%E2%80%93-Multiple-Entity-Typed-Result-Sets-from-a-Stored-Procedure.aspx) (*note, my server may take a few minutes for the disks to spin up as not too many people traffic my humble little blog*).

The short of it is in the CSDL section ..

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="myModel" ...>
    <EntityContainer Name="myModelEntities" ....>
    ......
    <!-- 
     this is what “function import” wrote, that I’m overwriting…         
     FunctionImport Name="MyMARS_Proc" ReturnType="Collection(myModel.Table_A)"/>
     -->
     <FunctionImport Name="MyMARS_Proc" >
        <ReturnType Type="Collection(myModel.Table_A)" EntitySet="Table_As"/>
        <ReturnType Type="Collection(myModel.Table_B)" EntitySet="Table_Bs"/>
     </FunctionImport>
```

Then in the MSL (C-S Mapping section) you'll want...

```
<edmx:Mappings>
  <Mapping Space="C-S" ....>
    <EntityContainerMapping  ....>

       <FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="MyMARS_Proc"
                               FunctionName="myModel.Store.MyMARS_Proc">
            <ResultMapping>
                <EntityTypeMapping  TypeName="myModel.Table_A"/>
            </ResultMapping>
            <ResultMapping>
                <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="myModel.Table_B"/>
            </ResultMapping>
       </FunctionImportMapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is quite interesting question. I played with .NET 4.5 Beta / VS11 Beta for a while and I have two observations:

- It looks like there is no support in designer for multiple result sets - everything must be mapped manually in EDMX opened as XML
- It looks like the former article about June CTP 2011 is no longer valid because MSL doesn't allow declaring multiple `ResultMapping` to map different result sets and each `ResultMapping` can map only single result set

**EDIT:**

I was wrong. It works at runtime. Only designer complains about EDMX validation but MSL itself accepts multiple `ResultMapping` elements. The original walkthrough linked in the question is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

I did this code

The procedure as following

```
           alter procedure dbo.proc_getmorethanonetable

          as
       select * from dbo.Orders
      select * from dbo.Items
     select * 
      from dbo.Users u
      inner join dbo.Orders o 
        on o.User_ID = u.User_ID
  go
```

The Code is so Simple 
Here we go

```
        using (var db = new EF_DEMOEntities())
              {
                   var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[proc_getmorethanonetable]";
                     try
                       {
                            db.Database.Connection.Open();
                            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                           {
                                 var orders =            
                                 ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<Order>(reader);
                                 GridView1.DataSource = orders.ToList();
                                 GridView1.DataBind();
                                 reader.NextResult();
                                var items =  
                           ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<Item>(reader);
                              GridView2.DataSource = items.ToList();
                              GridView2.DataBind();


                            }
                        }
                       finally
                       {
                            db.Database.Connection.Close();
                       }
                       }
```

and here you go :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this isn't really EF. This is just the old way where you use your model, but still have a ton of code.