# EntityFramework 6: ExecuteStoreQueryAsync with multiple result sets

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF 6 beta1. I have a simple stored proc that returns two result sets:

> ALTER PROCEDURE GetItemsByParentId
>
> @parentID int
>
> SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ParentID = @parentID
>
> SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ParentID = @parentID

I want to call that stored proc using my ObjectContext. I'm using database first and I have an edmx, but I don't want to import the stored proc as a function if I don't have to.

I created two simple classes Table1DTO and Table2DTO to store the results of the stored proc. For the first result set I call this:

> var result1 = ExecuteStoreQueryAsync< Table1DTO >("EXEC GetItemsByParentId @parentID", new SqlParameter("parentID", parentID));
>
> List table1DTOList = result1.ToList();

That works fine. Then for the second result set I'm trying this:

> var result2 = result.GetNextResult< Table2DTO >();
>
> List improvementDetailInfos = result2.ToList();

The problem is result2 is coming back as null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like splitting hairs, but Entity Framework *supports* multiple result sets.  The problem is that the Entity Framework *Tooling does not*.  This has been an issue since EF 4.1/4.2.  So you have three options (that I can think of):

1. split up your calls to only use single result sets
2. use an alternate technology (dapper?) for the few critical stored procedures that require multiple result sets
3. manually edit the EDMX to create a multi-result set mapping for `GetItemsByParentId`

To be honest I've wrestled with this in a number of scenarios and none of the options are great.    If you're something of a masochist, I [wrote up an example](http://milesquaretech.com/Blog/post/2012/03/19/Entity-Framework-5-%E2%80%93-Multiple-Entity-Typed-Result-Sets-from-a-Stored-Procedure.aspx) and [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314032/entity-framework-5-stored-procedure-with-multiple-result-sets/10419740#10419740) on how to edit the EDMX for multiple result sets.